# How to execute an R shiny script from the command line

Tags: r, cmd, shiny, rodbc

I've created a single R file 'myfile.R' which is composed of several functions, reading from an odbc connection, and of course the ui and server components for the shiny application. The goal is for the user to treat this as an executable, that is, I'd like them to be able to run this app without having to run Rstudio. Currently on this environment, Rstudio is installed (as are the relevant packages), what I'm currently writing in command line is:

```
Rscript myfile.R
```

The file looks to be successfully loaded, but the application itself does not 'pop up' towards me, infact nothing does, it just says that it is listening on http....
I was thinking of creating a bash script that could do this, and this seemed to be the most simple approach but this is not working.

Comment: Without seeing the code it’s impossible to say what might be going wrong. RStudio is irrelevant here, since it isn’t being used.

Comment: What happens if you visit the URL from "listening on http...." in your browser?

Comment: @Till that was an excellent idea, it has the app I've created there, now I just need to figure out how to make it automatically visit this URL

Comment: Does setting the `launch.browser` option work? 
`shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE)`

Comment: Yessir it did, thank you so much, @Till !!